# IE 10 crashes when script is loaded, unless a delay is introduced

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I recently learned that the app I'm working on frequently crashes Internet Explorer 10 - no error messages, just Windows' "The application stopped working". Looking at the Event Viewer shows what I gather is a null reference in mshtml.dll:

```
Faulting application name: iexplore.exe, version: 10.0.9200.17267, time stamp: 0x54e7f156
Faulting module name: MSHTML.dll, version: 10.0.9200.17267, time stamp: 0x54e803bf
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x004f9b17
Faulting process id: 0xeec
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0657e1d8a29f6
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSHTML.dll
```

I've discovered that this happens when loading the first script on the page, which is jQuery. I've tried two different versions: 1.10.2 and 1.11.2, with the same result.

It turns out that introducing a small delay before loading jQuery (and the rest of the scripts) solves the issue. I've added this snippet before all other scripts:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 10') >= 0) {
    var t = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() - t < 300);
}
```

This seemingly solves the problem. However, it is clearly very inelegant and I still don't know what the actual problem is.

Has anyone experienced something similar, and is there a better solution?

Comment: do any of your script tags have a defer or async attribute? Are the <script> blocks all in the <head>?
where do you call window.onload or DOMContentLoaded?

To debug your web pages loading....
f12>Debug tab, select "Break on all errors" (in IE11 also select the 'My code' option)
return to the browser and refresh the page... the DT will break on any errors.... (you should a least see on error is jquery sizzle).
Usually MSHTML errors are caused by third-party addons. IE10 does not recognize new ActiveXControl (which is used in Flash shims).
first...test in noAddons mode.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have not upgraded to IE11 yet...

Comment: @RobParsons Personally, I don't use IE at all... but on the internets, there are still people struggling with IE10. In particular, one of my customers, and I'm not in a position to tell them to upgrade.